# Notable changes when modeling unevenly univariate spaced time series as an evenly spaced multivariate time series?

Tags: time-series, modeling, bias, methodology, unevenly-spaced-time-series

When attempting to model univariate data (although, this could easily be extended to the multivariate case) that is unevenly spaced over time, a natural approach to be able to apply common time series methods would be to treat time as another variable to be modeled so that each observation is then a pair of a unix timestamp and a data value, both indexed by some sort of event time (say, the natural numbers: $0, 1, \dots$).

Aside from the change that we are now modeling two variables observed over "event time" which comes with the complications of modeling two variables, are there any other notable changes/problems/biases being introduced by this reframing?/are there methods for unevenly spaced time series that lend themselves more easily to this situation than changing to "event time"?